# Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address = 0X48) AVAudioPlayer (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I get a `Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address = 0X48)` every time I press 
a `button`. I checked my connections and my mp3 file "song" is correct. I'm not sure what's wrong. My buttons work perfectly fine but it's just the `AVAudioPlayer (var Player)` that is not allowing the buttons to crash the program and return the error. Any help would be much appreciated (I'm a beginner at Swift).

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    @IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton) {

        player.play()
    }

    @IBAction func pause(_ sender: UIButton) {
        player.pause()
    }

    @IBAction func replay(_ sender: UIButton) {
       player.currentTime = 0
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            do{
                let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "song", ofType: "mp3")
                try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
            }
            catch{
                //error
            }                                        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }            
}
```

Comment: Yea I checked my connections. I'm not sure what's wrong with player.play()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write same code project ,but not have any wrong

My code

```
var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
lazy var btn: UIButton = {
    var btn = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 20, y: 20, width: 60, height: 60))
    btn.backgroundColor = .red

    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.play), for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn
}()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(btn)
    do{
        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "song", ofType: "mp3")
        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
    }
    catch{
        //error
    }
}
func play() {
    player.play()
}
```

please check you this problem

1.Whether the player is running on the main thread？

2.song.mp3 is exist and it can playing

3.Whether the storyboard is in conflict